# How to get Real-time updates of a playlist in Spotify?

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to get the list of tracks from a Spotify playlist. But I need the updates of the playlist in **real time**. If any track gets added (or removed) in the playlist, I need a notification from Spotify API that the playlist is updated.

I first tried to accomplish my goal by getting the playlist data from Spotify API **every 10 minutes** and compare it to its previous version. But it's so inefficient.

I'm building the application with Flutter using [spotify 0.8.0](https://pub.dev/packages/spotify) package. But I'm okay with REST APIs.

Is there any other way for getting live update of a playlist?